# How to display image based on the screen size of the device?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a mobile app in PhoneGap using  HTML5,CSS3, Javascript and Jquery-mobile.

I have an html page with an img element to display an image. The problem i am facing is that with diffrent screen size it does not display based on the screen but the actual size of the image causing images to be displayed half. Is there a way i can automate this process so that it will display based on the screen size of the device ?

```
<img src="img\following_followers.png" alt="" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the CSS3 [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) property. This is part of what we call "responsive" design.

There are even ready-made themes available on the internet, just search up "responsive template".

You can also take a look at [this link](http://css-tricks.com/on-responsive-images/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa) may be of some help.

Technically, you can't access the screen's dimensions directly from CSS, nor can an element know about its parent's absolute dimensions without the help of JavaScript. Instead you usually express an element's dimensions relative to its parent, such as

```
#logo {
    width: 500px;
}

#logo img {
    width: 33%;
}
```

If an image's CSS height is not explicitly set or inherited, it'll scale with the width; the reverse is also true.

You can set an image to fill its parent container using `width: 100%` or `height: 100%`, but this may cause the image to overflow the container. The properties `max-width` and `max-height` can account for this. Try:

```
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

but be aware that most browsers by default allow a document to grow in height as necessary, so a `max-height: 100%` property will do very little if its parent container doesn't have some sort of restriction on its own height.

That said, Javascript can access the browser's dimensions directly with `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. **However,** these properties are only set when the page initially loads, and they won't change if the browser window is resized. `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` are more reliable.

As always, UX libraries like jQuery and Bootstrap.js make this kind of task much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're having the right meta tag. If not then add this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Then in css

```
<img src="img\following_followers.png" alt="" style="width:100%;height:100%;" >
```

Comment: thanks ! your solution did work but what it did in return was made the font look really small on the entire app? it just made everything small can i avoid that

Comment: try css `body { font-size:2em; }` in your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your style

```
 img {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
 }
```